# In Log4j what is the diffrence between LevelRangeFilter and Threshold?

Tags: java, log4j

What is the difference between `LevelRangeFilter` and `Threshold`? When would I use one versus the other?

```
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG"/>
</filter>
```

```
<param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options will have the same behavior. Threshold should be faster though.

You should use a 'filter' if you want major flexibility. Besides being able to define a LevelMin and LevelMax, filters allow you to implement your own logic and you can also chain them together if needed.

If you need only basic a basic 'threshold' functionality I would go with your second option.

You can get more details from the [AppenderSkeleton](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2//apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html) API. Note the simple `setThreshold` vs the `addFilter` and `decide` that determines if passing the `LoggingEvent` to other filters or not.